# What is the covariance for a Gaussian process when $0\le s<t$?

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes

Let $W$ be a Brownian motion and let $Y_t=\sigma^2 e^{-t}W_{e^{2t}}$. Note that $Y_t$ is a Gaussian process with
$$
E Y_t=\sigma^2 e^{-t}E[W_{e^{2t}}]=?
$$
Is it zero? How to show that?

Also, what is the covariance for $0\le s<t$,
$$
Cov(Y_s, Y_t)=Cov(\sigma^2 e^{-s}W_{e^{2s}}, \sigma^2 e^{-t}W_{e^{2t}})
$$

---

For the covariance part, I try to
$$
Cov(Y_s, Y_t)=Cov(Y_s, Y_t-Y_s+Y_s)
$$
But for the Gaussian part, we do not have the independent increments property. How to get the covariance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$EW_u=0$ for all $u$ and $EW_uW_v=\min \{u,v\}$. From this you should be able to do the computations yourself.  [Recall that $E(c X)=cEX$ for a constant $c$]. [Answer: $Cov (Y_s,Y_t)=\sigma^{4} e^{-|t-s|}$].

Comment: $W_t$ is a BM, but is still $W_{e^{2t}}$ a BM? Can we still use the definition of BM that $E W_u W_v=u\land v$? To conclude that $E W_{e^{2t}} W_{e^{2s}}=e^{2t}\land e^{2s}$?

Comment: $W_{e^{2t}}$ is just $W_u$ evaluated at $u=e^{2t}$. There is no need to study the process $(W_{e^{2t}})$. You are just over-thinking. @Hermi

Comment: Oh! So that is just a BM at a deterministic time $e^{2t}$, not a random process?

Comment: Yes, that is right.